# Modifying iOS IPA asset and resigning (preferably from Windows)

Tags: ios, code-signing, game-engine, ipa

I'm working on an iOS game.  I have access to mac, xcode, etc.  The issue is that my artists and designers do not.  I would like to give them an ipa and have them able to unzip, modify assets, and then rebuild and test the ipa without have to use a mac or xcode.  The ipa doesn't need to be installable on any iOS device other than their test device.  Is this possible?

I read a little bit about codesign that comes with xcode, but that appears to only run on a mac - are there alternatives?  It looks like Marmalade (and maybe UDK) provides this functionality (resigning on a pc) to their users, but I don't want to use those engines.

Ultimately I am simply looking for a way for an artist or designer to test out their changes without requiring them to rebuild the ipa from xcode or a mac - any ideas?  Is there a system for allowing artists or designers to add files to an iDevice that an app can access to self patch it's assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I could come up with was to use Dropbox's iOS API as a patch interface to download files into the document folder.  Then whenever I go to load a file from my installed folders, I first check to see if the new asset exists within the patch folder and if so I use that file instead.  A fairly basic concept that appears to be working surprisingly well for iOS devices.